# Mac Dropbox client not syncing; weird menubar behaviour

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, sync, dropbox

Old hackintosh with 10.6.3 on it. Everything used to work just fine, but about 2 weeks ago I noticed it wasn't syncing.

I've tried removing/reinstalling, rebooting, fixing permissions, wiping out the entire ~/Dropbox folder (local and via dropbox.com), rebooting, and nothing seems to work. No OS X updates have happened, and no firewall changes have been made.

I tried installing from the latest version from dropbox.com, but I CANNOT CLICK THE "sign in" button after install. It just won't click.

I reverted back to Dropbox 2.0.26 and 2.0.8, and that "installed", but the menubar dropdown is...chopped. It only shows some 42 pixels (height) of the popup.  I can scroll it, and at the bottom, it just says "Starting...".  I've left it there for a few days, and it never gets past that.

Any ideas? My next step may be to wipe the hackintosh and install ubuntu. :)